# Create action response in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core application I have the following action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {

  Reply reply = service.GetData();  

  return reply.Errors.Count > 0 ? HttpBadRequest(reply) : Ok(reply);

}
```

I get an error because HttpBadRequest and Ok are not of the same type.

I know I can use an IF but is there a way to create the response in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast both of them as an `IActionResult` as implied by your response.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{

    Reply reply = service.GetData(); 

    return reply.Errors.Count > 0 ? (IActionResult)HttpBadRequest(reply) : Ok(reply);

}
```